# Windows Server 2012/2016 simulated RAID6 in software with 4 disks

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, software-raid, raid6

Does anyone know how to emulate RAID6 in software on Windows server using 4 disks? The solution must provide for the failure of **any** two disks (like RAID-6 in Linux).

Thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Double parity storage spaces is the closest built-in solution to what you ask. It can tolerate loss of two disks.
But this is not exactly RAID 6 in terms of performance. Write performance will be limited to performance of one disk.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/deploy-standalone-storage-spaces

Comment: "...using 4 disks". Storage spaces wants 7 disks!

Comment: yup, my bad. Only 3rd party software then.